# SQL - How can I search for specific data in a text field? E.g. I require rows that include C1 + any char e.g. C1$ other than another number e.g. C19

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

I need to search a database for two specific values, these being C1 and C5 which appear in the notes in each row.

However, some notes contain information such as C128, C523, C100 – I do not want to pull these.

To complicate things even more, some notes contain the C1 and C5 on their own e.g. with a space directly after the number but some notes contain the C1 and C5 with letters directly after them e.g. C1DANNY, C5CLAIRE, C1RUN – I do need to pull these as well as those that only say C1 and C5.

E.g. Database

```
ID  Notes
1   C1
2   C128
3   C5
4   C1
5   C1DANNY
6   C25
7   C1RUN
8   C10
9   C523
10  C5!
```

So from the above database, I only want to pull rows: 1, 3, 4, 5, 7 and 10.

I don’t want to pull anything that has a number after the second digit such as line 8 above. I do want to pull everything that has any character apart from a number after the second digit such as line 3 and 10.

I should also mention I have been reading up about what wildcards I can use here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp but I feel I probably need to use an IF statement to loop round and check precisely what is included within each note but the database is quite big (hundreds of thousands of rows).

There is some code already written by a previous worker. The code in question being:

```
(
  esl.log_text LIKE 'C1%' OR
  esl.log_text LIKE 'C5%' OR
  esl.log_text LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + 'C1%' OR
  esl.log_text LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + 'C5%' OR
  esl.log_text LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + 'C1%' OR
  esl.log_text LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + 'C5%'
)
```

Unfortunately, this appears to be pulling lines that include C10 for example.
I am new to SQL and Stack Overflow and any assistance on what code I could use to achieve this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Haven't got time to test out a full answer but a general approach might be to split the field's value (substring() function maybe) so you get the first two characters. If they're C1 or C5 then that's good. Then split again to look at the other side of the string. If it's not parseable as a number then again that's good and you can select that row. It wasn't clear if you wanted the ones which have only whitespace after them or not?

Comment: Thanks ADyson, that makes sense and yes I do also require those with whitespace after them.

Comment: No problem. BTW is it me or is this data a bit of a mess. Surely there's a better way to store whatever these values represent so that you don't have to resort to string parsing to extract meaning from them.

Comment: You are right, it isn't great. Will be looking to see how we can move this forward but new to the role. For now, I have been given a query I need to resolve on what we have. On the plus side, I'm guessing this will mean lots to learn! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Notes
FROM dbo.Testing_Code AS T0
WHERE (LEFT(Notes, 2) IN ('C1', 'C5')) AND (ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Notes, 3, 20)) = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you Ruan, will do - much appreciated.

Comment: Pleasure, hope it helps